# How do I properly add a SKPhysicsBody to a drawn line using SKShapeNode in Spritekit?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, bitmask, skshapenode

I'm creating a game where the user must draw a line to collide with a ball to move it from one location to another.  I just can't seem to find a way to put a physics body that collides with another object. The drawn line goes through other objects.  I've tried several different SKPhysicBody init's on my shape, and none of them seem to work.

What's the best SKPhysicsBody initializer for a drawn line?

Are my category bit mask correct?

I understand the SkShapeNode can be converted to a SkSpriteNode, but I don't want to do this unless its the only way.

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var lines: [Line] = []
var lastTouch: CGPoint?
var touchLocation: CGPoint!
var linePhysics: CGPoint?
var ballCategory:UInt32 = 0b1
var lineCategory:UInt32 = 0b1 << 1
var goalCategory:UInt32 = 0b1 << 2
var floorCategory:UInt32 = 0b1 << 3

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    // assigns metal ball that was a color Sprite node, and is now a SKSpriteNode
    let metalBall:SKSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    //assigns physical properties
    metalBall.position = CGPoint(x: -150, y: 100)
    metalBall.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: metalBall.size.width / 2)
    metalBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    metalBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    metalBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
    metalBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = floorCategory | lineCategory




    let floor: SKSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "floor") as! SKSpriteNode
    floor.position = CGPoint (x: 0, y: -76)
    floor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: floor.size)
    floor.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    floor.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    floor.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = floorCategory
    floor.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ballCategory
}
/** 
 * Assigns the first touch location to a variable lastTouch
**/
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     if let firstTouch = touches.first {
          lastTouch = firstTouch.location(in: self)
    }
}
/**
 * Assigns a path to where the finger touches  then adds it to the line array and draws a path using shape nodes
**/
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let firstTouch = touches.first {
     touchLocation = firstTouch.location(in: self)
    //adds coordinates of lines to the line array
    lines.append(Line(start: lastTouch!, end: touchLocation))
    lastTouch = touchLocation
      }
    // path is a changeable variable that assigns a path depending on touch
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    for line in lines {
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: line.start.x, y: line.start.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line.end.x , y: line.end.y))
    }
    // colors in the path with ui color black
    let shape = SKShapeNode()
        shape.path = path
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black
        shape.lineWidth = 2
        addChild(shape)
        **shape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: shape.path!)**
        shape.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        shape.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        shape.physicsBody?.friction = 1
        shape.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.1
        shape.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
        shape.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        **shape.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = lineCategory
        shape.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask =  ballCategory**
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but whenever I have trouble, I try to boil everything down to the basics. I created a little project just now, and set it up to draw a dynamic line like you're doing. I attached an `SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom:)` like you did, but I left out all the rest. Then in the same function I added an `SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)` above the line, and added an `SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)` to it. When I draw the line, the ball falls onto it and rolls on it. Yes, you can use `SKShapeNode`s with physics. Sorry if little help. Try elaborating.